# PHP parse HTML page only when page has completely loaded

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, domdocument

I am trying to parse a HTML page using PHP with DOMDocument but there is a javascript that updates an element on the page. The DOMDocument loads the page BEFORE the javascript has updated the elements on the page. How to I parse the HTML only AFTER the page has been completely loaded?

Comment: DOMDocument does not include a JavaScript runtime engine, if that's your question.

Comment: This is not possible as PHP has already finished executing before your browser even receives the outputted html, you'll need to use ajax etc.

Answer (score 2):

Load the page into PhantomJS, wait for JavaScript to finish executing, then use the HTML that has been generated.

[php-phantomjs](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) should make that quite simple (see the "Request a URL with delay and output the reponse" example in the README).